# Is it logical to report standard deviation of the coefficient of Regression model?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, regression-coefficients

I had determined the coefficient for the variables using Multinomial Logit model. The software reported coefficient, t-value and standard error for the variable.

One of my senior want to include Standard Deviation of the coefficient as well. But the software doesn't report SD.

Does it make sense to interpret the coefficient with standard deviation? If yes, what can I do to get the standard deviation of the coefficient?

Thank you

Comment: By way of lending support to rvl's fine answer -- your colleague seems to misunderstand the meaning of the standard error of a coefficient. The first part of the first sentence of the Wikipedia article on [Standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) explains: "*The standard error (SE) is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of a statistic*".

Comment: I suspect your "senior" didn't understand the difference between a standard deviation and standard error.  When reporting the values of estimated coefficients, I think it's best to present confidence intervals.  A lot of information is contained in it.

Comment: Glen_b Thanks for the clarification.     @StatsStudent Presenting confidence interval seems to represent the coefficient well. But, how can I get confidence interval when the software that I am using does not report them?

Comment: @Droko, what software are you using?  I find it hard to believe, if you are using statistical software, that it doesn't provide a standard error or a confidence interval.

Comment: @StatsStudent The software is Easy Logit Modeler (free software esp. for discrete choice modeling). It does provide standard error. I think I can do that by using:  Lower limit = M - Z.95 * SE

Upper limit = M + Z.95*SE. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense; either that, or there's no distinction. The term "standard error" refers to the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of an estimate. There is no interpretation of "SD" for the regression coefficient apart from the SE that you already have in your printout.